# How to show that if $f(x)=x\sin x$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$ there's a sequence with $f(x_n)=c$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $f : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = x \sin x$. I'm trying to show that if $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is given, then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\lim x_n = +\infty$ and $f(x_n) = c$ for all $n$.

My try is that if $c$ is given we consider the horizontal line $y = c$. In that case, we first need to assure that there are numbers with $f(x) = c$. Now this is equivalent to $x\sin x = c$. This could be done with continuity of $f$ right? But here I'm trying to show this with just limits, without continuity arguments.

If I could show there's an infinite number of $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=c$ I believe we could easily build the sequence $(x_n)$.

So, if I'm not to use continuity, how could I show the claim? How can I show that $f(x)=c$ has infinite solutions and how can I build a sequence with the desired property from this?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Apply the intermediate value theorem repeatedly on successive intervals of $2\pi$

Answer (score 2):

I would try to prove that there is one such $x_n$ on the interval $[2n\pi, 2n\pi + 2\pi]$.

The function on this interval has a minimum that is smaller than $-2n\pi - \frac{3\pi}{2}$ and a maximum that is larger than $2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$, and is continuous.

Comment: I think the interval should be $[2n\pi,(2n+2)\pi]$.

Comment: @iiivooo I agree. I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks @5xum. In that case, I would need to pick the first $n$ so that $-2n\pi - 3\pi/2 < c < 2n\pi + \pi/2$, so that by the intermediate value theorem there would be some $x_n$ on that interval with $f(x_n) = c$ right? After picking this first $n$ we would simply need to do this for all next intervals right?

Comment: @user1620696 Absolutely correct. I believe the whole proof should not be too long when it's written down...